# How to Place a Grid in the View

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, camera

I'd like to get some advice/recommendations on placing a grid over a page's view. This is for a sample camera app, modeling off of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx . I have added a few modifications to the MainPage where I have a custom appbar implementation at the bottom, which is opaque and is over the `VideoCanvas` which takes up the entire screen. I'd like to add a button to toggle a grid on or off to better line up a new camera shot, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Should I create a user control and overlay the grid or do this in the MainPage, how best can I line this up to be uniform on all phone screen sizes, and any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

MainPage

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush"/>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>

        ...

    </Grid>
```

Comment: "To better line up a new camera shot"
What do you want the Grid to be lined up with in terms of UI? Where will the Grid be placed?

Comment: I was jsut thinking a simple 3x3 grid, two lines going horizontal and vertical to create it, so that the middle rectangle is in the middle of the screen. Since I have an app bar, i would have to make it so the grid did not go past the bottom 72 pixels of the page (portrait orientation), so I'd like to make it so the grid is placed above the appbar (since it is opaque).

Comment: Alright, well the only thing you need to worry about is the ApplicationBar Height on Portrait and Width at Landscape mode which is  fixed at 72 pixels. You need to bind the 3x3 Grid's Margin to a property on your ViewModel and change that value on page `OrientationChanged`. Chriss W. shows how the Layout should be. You would place both the Grid containing your Canvas and the 3x3 Grid you mention as Childen of another outer Grid. This way it should span the entire screen on all screen resolutions since the outer screen dimension are not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just draw it out and lay it over the view with a `Visibility` toggle, and if you wanted to get a little fancy place with things like `StrokeDashArray` etc to get a dotted line. You could also just draw your `Grid` and enable `ShowGridLines="True"` but that will give you blue/yellow dashed outlines unless you dig into it do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126541/how-to-highlight-the-border-lines-of-a-grid-control/9137618#9137618).

As a quick example;

```
<Grid>
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush"/>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>

        </Grid>

<!-- Lay it over the existing stuff -->

<Grid Visibility="Visible">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="9"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="9"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="9"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="7" Grid.RowSpan="9"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="9"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="9"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="9"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="9"/>

        </Grid>


    </Grid>
```

Hope this helps.